# How's DynaLoader's c library loaded?

Tags: perl

We know this module's function is `Dynamically load C libraries into Perl code` .

But how's its own c library loaded into Perl in the first place?

I judge it should have its own c library because I don't find the function `dl_load_file` right inside `DynaLoader.pm`,so it must be in some c library...

Comment: a secondary purpose is to create perl bindings for the C-level functions in the module's library; in the case of a statically linked module, only the secondary purpose applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynaloader is statically linked to Perl (managed by Configure), so that it is always available.  It wouldn't work very well if it had to be available itself to load itself.

The source for Dynloader is at [/ext/Dynaloader/ in the Perl distribution](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree/HEAD:/ext/DynaLoader), which contains a number of different implementations of dl_load_file for the various architectures on which Perl might run.

So yes, dl_load_file is in a library, but it ends up inside perl when perl gets built.

Comment: unless you build perl with dynamic loading turned off